# How to generate protein graphics for illustrating articles?

Tags: biochemistry, molecular-biology, software

The structure of insulin shown below appears in [a Wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insulin).

What software was (or can be) used to create pictures of this type?

[image: structure of insulin]

Comment: Have you tried to Google [protein 3D visualization](https://www.google.ca/search?q=protein+3D+vizualization&oq=protein+3D+vizualization&aqs=chrome..69i57.6326j1j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)?

Comment: Please give a reference to this particular example. You are surely aware that Wikipedia's contributors (not users) are completely independent and thus use whatever software they choose to create molecular images. This is hardly a question about biology, and, as @Remi.b  said, you can find out about different molecular graphics software. You might also wish to look at the PDB site, which used two alternatives in their displays. But none are simple push-button programs, but require you to learn proprietory scripting commands.

Comment: I really appreciate your comments 

Comment: there are plenty. Try autodock for a start

Answer (score 3):

All comments are great, there are numerous software programs that allow you to make such images.

---

**Gathering information about the insulin structure**

By simply clicking on the [image in wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insulin) it will provide you with  valuable information:

> Created by Isaac Yonemoto created with en:pymol, en:inkscape, and
>   en:gimp from NMR structure 1ai0 in the en:pdb. Ref: Chang, X.,
>   Jorgensen, A.M., Bardrum, P., Led, J.J.

So the creators used [pymol](https://pymol.org/2/), [inkscape](https://inkscape.org/nl/) and [gimp](https://www.gimp.org/), but let's dig a bit deeper. Unfortunately Isaac Yonemoto, the editor of this wiki, did not provide a direct link to the original publication (see [wiki file history](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:InsulinHexamer.jpg)). However by searching the author names in combination with `insulin` we quickly find the article: [Solution structures of the R6 human insulin hexamer](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/9235985). In the first paragraph we see:

> The atomic coordinates of the 20 refined hexamer structures and the
>   NMR-derived restraints have been deposited in the Brookhaven Data Bank
>   (PDB ID codes 1AIY and 1AI0 for the symmetric and the nonsymmetric
>   hexamer, respectively)

You can find the structure that was depicted in this wiki article by searching the [PDB id](https://www.rcsb.org/structure/1AIY).

---

**Creation vs visualization**
You can interpret 'create' in your question in two ways here:

- Creating this whole structure from nothing
- Visualizing a structure someone else determined

If you refer to the former you should look at the article corresponding to this structure. Note that this is quite detailed and requires  knowledge of several concepts, such as molecular dynamics and NMR spectroscopy. If you refer to the latter than you should take a look at the programs mentioned earlier such as [pymol](https://pymol.org/2/), [inkscape](https://inkscape.org/nl/) and [gimp](https://www.gimp.org/)

---

**Not generalizable**
This boils down to what @David already said in his comment:

> You are surely aware that Wikipedia's contributors (not users) are
>   completely independent and thus use whatever software they choose to
>   create molecular images.

Comment: Just to add, the author of that specific image did cite the PDB ID which allows you to find the structure, paper, etc in RCSB.